# Undefined reference, but linked and included

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, linker

In my Eclipse C/C++ project there is this `undefined reference` error which doesn't go away, doesn't matter what  I do. I already changed the link order, checked if all files are compiled and included, basically everything, which is recommended in the in the Internet, when facing this problem.

**Here's my program**:

[...] - means that there is more code, which doesn't relate.

*menulib.h*

```
[...]
void start_GUI( void );
[...]
```

*start_GUI.c* - **Note this is a `.c`-File**

```
#include "menulib.h"


void start_GUI( void )
{
 [...]
}
```

*coreInterface.h*

```
#ifndef COREINTERFACE_H_
#define COREINTERFACE_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
/** only include the Core when compiled for C++ */
#include "Core.h"
#endif /* #ifdef CORE */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void init_GUI( Core* core);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* COREINTERFACE_H_ */
```

*coreInterface.cpp* - **Note this is a `.cpp`-File**

```
#include "coreInterface.h"
#include "menulib.h"

void init_GUI( Core* core)
{
    gui_core =  core;
    start_GUI();            // <--- **error appears here** - calls a .c file
}
```

**Here's the error in the makefile** (the auto generated one from Eclipse):

```
g++ -L/home/PC/the_Project/menu_GUI -o "the_Project"  [...]  ./menu_GUI/coreInterface.o [...] ./menu_GUI/start_GUI.o  [...]   -lcurses
./menu_GUI/coreInterface.o: In function `init_GUI':
/home/PC/the_Project/Default/../menu_GUI/coreInterface.cpp:23: undefined reference to `start_GUI()'
```

I believe this is coming from merging the `.c` and `.cpp` files. Still I couldn't solve it. Has anyone an idea?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

```
#include "coreInterface.h"
extern "C" {
#include "menulib.h"
}

void init_GUI( Core* core)
{
    gui_core =  core;
    start_GUI();           
}
```

Comment: no way it's working, I was looking at this for hours

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you share the menulib.h header between C and C++ without specifying to C++ compiler that the function `start_GUI` is defined in C. Use `extern "C"` in #ifdef not only for `init_GUI`, but also for `start_GUI`.

Comment: If I surround the `start_GUI` with an `extern "C" { ... }` in the `menulib.h` I get a different error: `expected identifier or »(« before string constant`

Comment: When you say "I get an error" *always* state where you see it. Otherwise it is impossible to help you. So is the error reported when you compile C or C++ file?

Comment: I put the `extern "C" ...` into the menulib.h instead of the coreInterface.cpp - the problem is solved when changing the code like @MassimoCosta mentioned